# Magento output (lowest) price of grouped products in view.phtml

Tags: php, magento

I try to output the lowest price of grouped products in the file view.phtml.
The lowest price should be inserted near the top. For now we use a additional 
attribute to display it. But that is just a workaround.

I tried different codes but no one is working:

`<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>`

or

```
<?php $_finalPriceInclTax = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_item, $_item->getFinalPrice(), true) ?>
```

but nothing seems to work.

Maybe you have some idea how to display the price, thank you in advance!

Christian

Answer (score 1):

This gets the children and should return the lowest price of the groupedProduct. 
I did not test this.

```
public function prepareGroupedProductPrice($groupedProduct)
{
$aProductIds =    $groupedProduct->getTypeInstance()->getChildrenIds($groupedProduct->getId());

$prices = array();
foreach ($aProductIds as $ids) {
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $aProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
        $prices[] = $aProduct->getPriceModel()->getPrice($aProduct);
    }
}

krsort($prices);
$prices = array_shift($prices);
return $prices;
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply! But when I past the code in the view.phtml I got an error in the first line `public function prepareGroupedProductPrice($groupedProduct)`